# How to set page numbers in XSLT having multiple simple-page-master?.This is for dynamically inserting pagenumbers in PDF

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT file having multiple simple-page-master. The multiple simple-page-master is used for setting different height and width.

Here I am facing an issue that the pagenumbers corresponding to each simple-page-master starts with 1.

I used < fo:page-number/> for dynamically generating Page numbers.

I also want to get the total number of pages since I have to write Page numbers as

Page 1 of 20

I need pagenumbers in a sequence.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh without more samples, it's hard to try an answer...

I gamble one but quite blindly :

You should have some  somewhere. Add a pagenumber param in it. And in your  add .
You should be able to output the page number via the param. To get the total number of simple-page-master, add another param or use the XPath count(//simple-page-master) (better to count once and use params).